# Text is getting overlap

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

here i have got a problem with my layout.xml.here i am trying to list full details of an event in here all the text overlaps on to each other when i am trying to edit it Through java file.As in the following pic i attached in the que.any help is thank full.

**Layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Logout" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Event Name :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Eventname"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:text="Location :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Contact person :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Contact"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Start Date :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="End Date :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/End"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Start"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Description :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Location"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="CALL"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Eventname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Logout" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Event Name :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Eventname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Location :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact person :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start Date :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="End Date :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/End"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="CALL"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</LinearLayout>
```